# How send same data to multiple objects in different views or view controllers?

Tags: ios, oop

I have application with documents in iOS7. I'm using core data to manage data in every document and view controllers to edit this document using navigation. In document editing views you can find a lot of elements with color lines or shapes, all of them needs to be changed when I'm changing parameter in color picker.

What is the best way to assign data to each element? Should I use delegates, but this is multidirectional call. Should I use singleton? Blocks? Or just point all elements to one color object, but how to do this in XCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those views are custom Objects, use `NSNotificationCenter`.
Create a notification and set all other views as observers to this notification.When you fire notification set color value in dictionary, and all the observers(views) gets this dictionary.

Now, in the selector method change color value accordingly.

**Code** ->
For all the views for which you want to change color, add them as observers for our notification name "changeColor"

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(colorChange:) name:@"changeColor" object:nil];
```

And to change the color value to particular color in all views,fire notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"changeColor" object:nil userInfo:@{@"finalColor": [UIColor redColor}];
```

This results in calling of `SEL(colorChange)` in all the observers.

```
-(void)colorChange{
   NSDictionary *userInfo =notification.userInfo;
   view.backgroundColor =userInfo[@"finalColor"];
}
```

Remove the observer in `dealloc`,

```
-(void)dealloc{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]` in `dealloc` if you're registering the notification to a class instance since NSNotificationCenter keeps `unsafe_unretained` pointers to each registered observer.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer santhu and thanks for mentioning about memory management John. I will check this answer as accepted answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options. Here are a few.

NSNotification

Delegation

KVO (key value observing)

IBOutletCollection

Enumerating a collection.

Each have trade offs and benefits.

Comment: With your help I found good article about when to use some of these options. If someone wants to know more, please read here: [link](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/)